# Does a small electrical panel need a main breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My house has the main breaker provided and installed by the electric company, that's regulated to 15A, and a panel that only has an old nonstandard 16A breaker.

I live in Portugal (I believe is same standards as EU). I am upgrading the electrical panel and I currently have a 40A/0,03A differential and a main 40A breaker, then for distribution after those I have one 32A, four 16A and one 10A breakers.

But I have seen a few schematics without the main breaker (in my case the 40A). Do I really need the 40A breaker on my installation considering that I have the company main breaker just before the panel?

*Note that the set up is meant to handle upgrades to the contracted power to at least 28A.*

Comment: You've seen schematics for _primary_ panels without a disconnect? That's allowed in some cases for _subpanels_, but I don't think a main panel can be without a disconnect. What's your nominal voltage there?

Comment: Just a general comment that should be good world wide.  Having a main disconnect/main breaker where it is easy to turn off is good.  This should protect  the panels, so having a main breaker in the panel becomes less needed/optional.

Comment: The voltage is 230/240v, and yes is the primary panel, but with the company breaker right by its side, accessible, if that matters.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your local-to-Portugal standards, but I think it's common in the EU for your main device to be an RCD (Residual Current Device, which detects leakage by comparing live and neutral currents - what we call a ground fault circuit interrupter, typically with different values for when it trips, though) that feeds everything else, rather than having many separate RCDs - which would be one reason to have it, even if the company supply breaker is right there, unless the company supply breaker is of that type.

Comment: I find it hard to find relevant or up to date information regarding what is necessary or optional. Specially since when looking up on google I get Brazilian info that matches Portuguese language and have much more internet traffic but has different standards. If not mistaken that RDC is the differential I mentioned, I have CDC240p from Hager, hand the schematics that I see never fail to have one of this kind, but is really the simple breaker that would come after the differential that I am unsure, I don't see a proper reason to have it.

Comment: If the extra panels are close together(same room) then other main breakers not really needed.  If the panels are far apart, then having a main breaker in them is handy, but not needed.  You/electrician just have to walk a distance to work on the far panel.

Comment: Really the best place to ask is at your local building/electrical permit office/department.  Electrical codes are usually country wide with the local city/town/state/province having their own extra code(if not just the country code) to go by.  Example is most of the U.S. can use electrical cable with conduit being an option, but certain states/cities allow only wires in conduit, no cables allowed/legal.

Comment: I went to the electricity shop (its government owned and regulates all electricity companies and provides the public infrastructure) to get info on the laws regarding grounding on old houses, they didn't know what "grounding" is and told me to hire an electrician. Any way I will hire one to certify my job once is done, hopefully I don't break any laws until then! But this seems to be a minor issue that would be easy to fix if necessary.

Comment: I missed that. I see no point  in having both a 40A RCD AND a 40A main breaker, since (as far as I understand) the RCD is itself also a breaker. On the other hand, if you already have them, I don't see any harm in having both, either.

Comment: For now I will return the piece, since aside from the money it fills space on the already small panel, I now have only 3 slots left but I can easily fill them in the future

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't need a main breaker *per se* i.e. for its role as a circuit breaker.   However all breakers are at least one other thing:

- a disconnect switch
- an RCD or GFCI

Quite often you don't need a *breaker*, but you do need *one of those other things*.   And when you try to actually procure that other thing, you find that economies of scale have screwed up the market, and made "breaker *and your thing*" to actually be cheaper than "just your thing by itself".

So, you go with the flow and accept an entirely redundant breaker simply to get the other thing.